# Changing Desktop environment?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, package-management, desktop-environment

I am considering a change from Windows 7 to any Linux distro. I prefer Linux Mint because it looks like Windows to some extent (in pictures at least, so I would like to give it a try).

I want to know whether I can change the Desktop Environment by downloading them to a USB stick from another computer and installing it on my PC because I do not have sufficient bandwidth to download them. If it is possible, then I would ask my friend to download them and install it on my pc.

Is it possible to download softwares to removable media and install them to other pcs?

Comment: Any Unix desktop may be made to look like the default on any other Unix, AFAIK. It's just a matter of installing the themes and the actual desktop software. Look instead at (package) management tools etc. when choosing a Unix.

Answer (score 1):

Recommendations are personal and liable to become out of date. That said, I would not disagree with your idea of [Linux Mint Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/) - this is probably the prettiest (most elegant-looking) Linux distro *at the moment*. But whichever distro you select, I suggest you try it first in a virtual machine. You can download [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and then download a [Cinnamon virtual machine](http://www.osboxes.org/linux-mint-17-cinnamon-mate-images-available-virtualbox-vmware/) to try (I did!)

When you have decided it can do everything you need, you can then look into installing it as dual-boot with Windows...

You can download all of this software from another computer, put them on a USB stick and then install them from the stick to your working machine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to download the desktop environment to a usb stick?

Comment: @RogUE - not sure what you mean?

Comment: I would like to know that is it possible to download a desktop environment(like GNOME 3) to a usb stick and then install it in my pc?

Comment: not to Windows I don't think. Many Linux distros support multiple desktops (Gnome 3, KDE, Mate etc) and it might be possible to install one by USB, but it is easier to start off with the desktop environment that you want.

Comment: I don't like to use virtual machines, Does Linux Mint has Live CD option, I would prefer this?

Comment: I dont mean a windows machine but a pc with Mint.

Comment: If you are using a LiveCD then it doesn't matter what OS you have on your hard disk, you will boot from the LiveCD and run that OS. Sure there is Linux Mint LiveCD [here](http://livecdlist.com/linux-mint/). Google is your friend :-)

Comment: I do not think that Mint comes with Cinnamon as well as Mate, if it does, then why do they give seperate downloads for each environment?

Comment: Mate and Cinnamon are alternatives, of course... Good luck!

Comment: @RogUE: `why do they give seperate downloads for each environment?` -- There can be multiple reasons for it. First, if I only want Cinnamon then why should I waste my precious bandwidth (think of some third world country here) in downloading Mate or KDE or XFCE too. Won't make sense. The other reason is about size, some distributions prefer to shrink ISO's size to be under 700MB but I don't think any popular distribution is doing it considering DVDs are also cheap and everywhere.

Comment: @RogUE: However, OpenSUSE used to offer (don't know present scenario) a DVD with all DEs on its website. You can ask LinuxMint community to offer such too.

Comment: `Is it possible to download the desktop environment to a usb stick? - `Look on Google about "how to make a persistent bootable Linux pendrive?"  By making your USB persistent, you can download the DEs in Live session and try them but I never checked whether they will get installed too if you try installing Linux in HDD.

Comment: @Firelord That's not what OP meant. He asked whether it was possible to download the DE package (for example, in Arch Linux, that would be [`cinnamon-3.2.8-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/cinnamon/download), for Antergos it would be [`cinnamon-3.4.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`](https://repo.antergos.info/antergos/x86_64/cinnamon-3.4.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz), etc. to a USB stick and use these to install the DE locally.

Answer (score 0):

A desktop environment is just a set of bits like anything else you run on a computer - you can download your environment to a USB stick or DVD/CD - whatever. Download the .rpm or .deb and put it anywhere you want.

One thing I would say is that you should be more concerned about your machine resources than looking like Windows. The basics are identical for all graphical desktops.

If you can use Windows, then you can use any Linux desktop, except with Linux you can always fall back on a decent command-line interface. I've never used power shell so I don't know what Windows is like now, but Linux/Unix was designed for command line first, GUIs second.

I know that I use Xfce - lightweight, but I prefer that to heavy (i.e. slow) KDE or Gnome behemoths - but YMMV. Even decent machines can be swamped by the heavier desktops.

Comment: I use windows command prompt, never tried PowerShell. I have seen some commands for Linux which appears to be strange for me, that's why I have been avoiding linux till now.

Comment: The Linux command line is infinitely more powerful than DOS. It may seem cryptic at first, but when you go to the trouble of learning it, it's like suddenly being able to read James Joyce instead of the free newspaper from the local supermarket. I'm not blindly knocking Windows here (never used Power Shell), these are the facts AFAIC. Check out the Art of Unix Programming [here](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/) by Eric Raymond, a Linux evangalist.

Comment: What are the precautions I have to take before installing Mint?

Comment: Dual boot or single OS?

Comment: I have seen many help requests saying that after dual booting linux distro with windows, they no longer can access windows. In replies, it is said that MBR or something has been lost and you have to recover it, so I am asking.

Comment: Windows is selfish - you have to install it first (1/2 of HDD?). Just make sure you have backups of all important files and you can't really go wrong. I've used dual boot machines for ages without problems. You could try the VM solution proposed by another poster - at least you'll know what you're getting into without blowing away your Windows install.

Comment: When I say Windows is selfish, it deletes all other OSs from the MBR - or at least it used to. This may have changed with UEFI booting and stuff - but I don't know much about that.

Comment: "1/2 of HDD?"  What does that mean?

Comment: What I meant was to install Windows first on (say, for example) 1/2 of the HDD (Hard Disk Drive). My apologies for not being clear. BTW, reinstalling Windows will wipe all your data on your original Windows install - just, as I said, back up  your important files before reinstalling, partitioning - any operation of that nature.

Comment: I already have windows installed in my device.

Comment: @Verace: When reinstalling Windows 7, if you don't choose to format your drive then your old Windows files can be found in new installation  under root directory (C:\). The directory's name is `Windows.old`.

Comment: To RogUE - yes, I already understood that you had Windows installed, but if you want to install Linux, you'll have to do a new install (unless you run a VM which you've said you don't want to do). @Firelord yes, but what happens if you **do** want to format your drive since you're making a dual boot machine? Anyway, backing up is **always** the best strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I very much agree with [gogoud's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194189/154671), and this is just expanding on it (too long to comment).

---

> I am consodering a change from win7 to any linux distro

Good move. I did the same a few months ago and didn't look back.

> I want to know whether I can change the envirnonment by downloading
>   them to a usb stick from another computer and installing it in my pc
>   (...) is it possible to download softwares to removable media and
>   install them to other pcs?

It sure is. For Linux Mint, you can download packages in `.deb` format here: http://packages.linuxmint.com/

Each distribution has a command-line syntax for installing locally-available packages. I'm not familiar with Mint, but in [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) the package manager is called `pacman` (yeah), so you would use the `pacman -S <package_name>` syntax to install from the online repository or `pacman -U <package_file_name>` to install from a local disk or USB drive. Using the [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(software)) package for illustrating:

```
pacman -S cinnamon
```

for online installing, and

```
pacman -U cinnamon-3.2.8-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

to install from the `cinnamon-3.2.8-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz` file you have downloaded elsewhere - and you may prefer to specify the full directory path instead.

Bear in mind that Desktop Environments are very complex and usually not contained in a single standalone package. If you have a look at the [Arch Repository entry](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/cinnamon/) you'll find that Cinnamon has a number of dependencies, and some of those are unlikely to be present in the system so you'll have to install them manually beforehand (except if using `pacman -S` which deals with everything for you). For Cinnamon specifically, they would be: `cinnamon-control-center`, `cinnamon-menus`, `cinnamon-screensaver`, `cinnamon-session`, `cinnamon-settings-daemon`, `cinnamon-translations`, `cjs`, `muffin` and `nemo` - at the very least.

---

Linux Mint is sure easier to set up and get going, and if you choose this distro, you should know (and already do, probably) that they offer different "flavors" when [downloading from the website](https://www.linuxmint.com/download.php), each integrating a different Desktop Environment. The Cinnamon and MATE editions are more "traditional", while the newer ones sure have their niches.

Now that you know that switching between DE's won't be *exactly* easy - the Mint team puts a good effort in testing their integration and it's quite non-trivial-, if possible, do practice on a Virtual Machine before you make your choice.